# Gostaria que minha MODAL fosse aberta de X em X horas, ou 1x ao dia

Tags: javascript, modal, localstorage, popup

Estou criando uma modal, e ja dei uma revirada na internet atrás, porém  não achei.

Gostaria que minha modal fosse aberta de 2 em 2 horas.

o codigo que estou usando no momento é este

- ```
   <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".closeWS").click(function() {
         $(".alertWS").fadeOut();
     });
     });
     var isAndroid=navigator.userAgent.match("Android"),msgCheckApp=localStorage.getItem("msgAPP");isAndroid&&"ok"==msgCheckApp&&(document.querySelector(".alertWS").style.display="none");
  </script>*
  ```

Comment: O navegador irá ficar aberto durante o dia fixado na mesma página?

Answer (score -4):

Isso é bem simples de fazer, mas preciso entender o que você quer. Pois é possível verificar o tempo corrido, exe: agora 14:00, quando for 16:00 o modal abre, porém nessse caso, a página precisará estar aberta, pois ele sempre vai pegar o tempo atual para verificação e a outra maneira seria, abrir em determinada hora pré estabelicida, exe: 00:00... 02:00... 12:00 e etc... outra coisa, você está verificando se o user agent é Android, mas se trata de uma aplicação web, certo ? responda ai que te ajudamos.

Um é o código abaixo usando o local storage que você já usa, para salver a última vez que foi aberto (mas há várias maneiras de fazer isso)

Dica: use JS ao invés de JQuery

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".closeWS").click(function() {
      $(".alertWS").fadeOut();
    });
  });

  // Função para abrir o modal
  function abrirModal() {
    $(".alertWS").fadeIn();
  }

  // Verifica se já passaram 2 horas desde a última vez que o modal foi aberto
  function verificarTempoModal() {
    var ultimaAbertura = localStorage.getItem("ultimaAbertura");
    var agora = new Date().getTime();
    var duasHoras = 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 2 horas em milissegundos

    if (!ultimaAbertura || (agora - ultimaAbertura) >= duasHoras) {
      abrirModal();
      localStorage.setItem("ultimaAbertura", agora);
    }
  }

  // Executa a verificação inicialmente
  verificarTempoModal();

  // Define o temporizador para executar a verificação a cada 2 horas
  setInterval(verificarTempoModal, 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // 2 horas em milissegundos
</script>
```

Comment: a parte do codigo, 

'**var isAndroid=navigator.userAgent.match("Android"),msgCheckApp=localStorage.getItem("msgAPP");isAndroid&&"ok"==msgCheckApp&&(document.querySelector(".alertWS").style.display="none");**'

é uma parte que venho junto com o codigo que consegui na net.

sim, seria interessante exibir em horários determinados, tipo de 14 , 16, 18

Answer (score -4):

Tente isso

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    function checkModalOpening() {
      var now = new Date();
      var hours = now.getHours();
      var minutes = now.getMinutes();

      // Verificar se o horário atual é um múltiplo de 2
      if (hours % 2 === 0 && minutes === 0) {
        $(".alertWS").fadeIn();
      }
    }

    $(".closeWS").click(function() {
      $(".alertWS").fadeOut();
    });

    // Agendar a verificação a cada minuto
    setInterval(checkModalOpening, 60 * 1000);
  });
</script>
```